# How to get error location from json.loads in Python

Tags: python, json

When I use json.loads in Python 3 and catch any resulting errors, like:

```
try:
  data = json.loads(string)
except ValueError as err:
  print(err)
```

I get a helpful message like:

```
Expecting ',' delimiter: line 12 column 12 (char 271)
```

I would like to be able to display this to the user, along with exactly the location which is causing the problem (I am reading in user-written JSON). How can I get out the line and column?

I could use a regex on err, but that feels like a bad idea, as I don't know if this message is internationalised, and could change in different versions of python. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3.5 and up, a specialized [`JSONDecodeError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) will be raised instead of `ValueError`. It has several useful attributes - quoting from the documentation:

> `msg`: The unformatted error message.
> `doc`: The JSON document being parsed.
> `pos`: The start index of `doc` where parsing failed.
> `lineno`: The line corresponding to `pos`.
> `colno`: The column corresponding to `pos`.

Answer (score 10):

[This answer is outdated. See other answers for modern python versions]

Scanning the [json/decoder.py source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/4c4f31a1b706/Lib/json/decoder.py), we can see that the decoder's error messages are constructed using the `errmsg` function:

```
def errmsg(msg, doc, pos, end=None):
    # Note that this function is called from _json
    lineno, colno = linecol(doc, pos)
    if end is None:
        fmt = '{0}: line {1} column {2} (char {3})'
        return fmt.format(msg, lineno, colno, pos)
        #fmt = '%s: line %d column %d (char %d)'
        #return fmt % (msg, lineno, colno, pos)
    endlineno, endcolno = linecol(doc, end)
    fmt = '{0}: line {1} column {2} - line {3} column {4} (char {5} - {6})'
    return fmt.format(msg, lineno, colno, endlineno, endcolno, pos, end)
    #fmt = '%s: line %d column %d - line %d column %d (char %d - %d)'
    #return fmt % (msg, lineno, colno, endlineno, endcolno, pos, end)
```

Since this is a pure-python module, it's easy to wrap this function with a custom one. This process is known as [monkey patching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch):

```
import json

original_errmsg= json.decoder.errmsg

def our_errmsg(msg, doc, pos, end=None):
    json.last_error_position= json.decoder.linecol(doc, pos)
    return original_errmsg(msg, doc, pos, end)

json.decoder.errmsg= our_errmsg

try:
    data = json.loads('{1:}')
except ValueError as e:
    print("error at", json.last_error_position)
```

Obviously, this solution is not ideal, since the implementation may change at any time, although it's still better than relying on the message. You should check if `errmsg` exists before patching (and possibly if there's no other arguments, or use varargs).

Comment: This is very interesting, but I think I'd prefer to regex the string, as I can always do something else if my regex fails to match in a future version, but this could (it seems to me) lead to some really horrible side-effects.

However, this does also still answer the question as 'no', and also let me look up all the formats of message I could get back. Thanks!

Comment: I think it would be nicer if the json parser returned a more qualified Exception which contains these fields. I have opened an [issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue19361) for it.

Comment: I tried this in my code but got `AttributeError: module 'json' has no attribute 'last_error_position'`

Answer (score 5):

If you use [simplejson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/) library, you get a well qualified `JSONDecodeError`:

```py
class JSONDecodeError(ValueError):
   """Subclass of ValueError with the following additional properties:

   msg: The unformatted error message
   doc: The JSON document being parsed
   pos: The start index of doc where parsing failed
   end: The end index of doc where parsing failed (may be None)
   lineno: The line corresponding to pos
   colno: The column corresponding to pos
   endlineno: The line corresponding to end (may be None)
   endcolno: The column corresponding to end (may be None)

   """
```

Hopefully, this will be [merged into stdlib](http://bugs.python.org/issue19361) soon.

Answer (score 1):

if json object is small, Past your Json object here 
http://jsonlint.com/
it gives where json breaks.

Comment: I want to use this in a program, while that website is helpful I wouldn't want to start calling it within my code!